# jsonschema library validate a number as a string with no upper bound

Tags: python, regex, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Using:

```
from jsonschema import validate
import jsonschema
```

I am trying to validate a minimum of 4096 with no upper bound on a string using JSON schema. I see regex pattern matching may be an option but unsure of how to do this with no upper bound.

```
json_data = {"value": "4096"}

# what I would like to do
json_schema = {"type": "string", "minimum": 4096}
try:
    validate(json_data, schema=json_schema)
    return True
except jsonschema.ValidationError:
    return False
```

Comment: Why can't you use `number`? If it is a variant-but-strict field, you could use `oneOf` to reflect.

Comment: A string is a string and a number is a number. In JSON Schema, you can validate the length of a string or the value of a number, but the inverse of those would require parsing JSON values into other types, and that's outside the scope of JSON Schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to [create](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/creating/#jsonschema.validators.create) a custom [validator](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validate/#jsonschema.IValidator) that you can use to perform the custom validation you need.

```
import jsonschema

json_schema = {
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
        'value': {
            'type': 'string',
            'minimum': 4096,
        },
    }
}


def is_gte(validator, value, instance, schema):
    if not instance.isdigit():
        yield jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError("Not a number")
    if int(instance) < value:
        yield jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError("Below required number")

all_validators = dict(jsonschema.Draft7Validator.VALIDATORS)
all_validators['minimum'] = is_gte

CustomValidator = jsonschema.validators.create(
    meta_schema=jsonschema.Draft7Validator.META_SCHEMA,
    validators=all_validators,
)
custom_validator = CustomValidator(json_schema)


for json_data in [
    {"value": 4096},  # Value not a string
    {"value": "4096"},  # Correct
    {"value": "496"},  # Below
    {"value": "13196"},  # above
    {"value": "11a96"},  # Invalid number
]:
    print("=" * 50)
    print(json_data)
    try:
        custom_validator.validate(json_data)
    except jsonschema.ValidationError as error:
        print("Invalid", error)
    else:
        print("Valid")
```

**Output**

```
==================================================
{'value': 4096}
Invalid 4096 is not of type 'string'

Failed validating 'type' in schema['properties']['value']:
    {'minimum': 4096, 'type': 'string'}

On instance['value']:
    4096
==================================================
{'value': '4096'}
Valid
==================================================
{'value': '496'}
Invalid Below required number

Failed validating 'minimum' in schema['properties']['value']:
    {'minimum': 4096, 'type': 'string'}

On instance['value']:
    '496'
==================================================
{'value': '13196'}
Valid
==================================================
{'value': '11a96'}
Invalid Not a number

Failed validating 'minimum' in schema['properties']['value']:
    {'minimum': 4096, 'type': 'string'}

On instance['value']:
    '11a96'
```

Reference:

- https://lat.sk/2017/03/custom-json-schema-type-validator-format-python/

Answer (score 1):

the `minimum` keyword does not apply to strings. it might be possible to do this with regex patterns, but it would be an ugly, bad implementation. this requirement is not well-suited for JSON schema and is better handled by an application's business logic.